# Consume from Existing GCP pubsub Subscription

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, google-cloud-pubsub, spring-cloud-gcp

I am trying to use the sample code hosted in this repo. https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gcp/tree/master/spring-cloud-gcp-samples/spring-cloud-gcp-pubsub-binder-sample I want the app to consume messages from an existing subscription. But the binder tries to always create a new topic and a new subscription for the newly created topic. What properties do I need to set to make the binder consume from existing subscription

Comment: When you say "this code," what code do you mean? You haven't provided any code.

Comment: Thanks. Missed to add the URL

Answer (score 1):

From reading the [implementation](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gcp/blob/72d746486fedd19b16ead3cdbbcfb48c3e90c3a9/spring-cloud-gcp-pubsub-stream-binder/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/gcp/stream/binder/pubsub/provisioning/PubSubChannelProvisioner.java#L77) of the Spring GCP Pub/Sub Stream Binder, reusing an existing subscription is done when a group name is set in application.properties. If that’s not happening, you should file an issue report in this repo. You may also want to try [disabling resource auto-creation](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gcp/blob/72d746486fedd19b16ead3cdbbcfb48c3e90c3a9/spring-cloud-gcp-pubsub-stream-binder/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/gcp/stream/binder/pubsub/provisioning/PubSubChannelProvisioner.java#L91).